# Post listing in admin is not showing in WordPress using SQL server and IIS

Tags: sql-server, wordpress, iis

I have recently prepared a fresh wordpress install with SQL server and IIS. WordPress version is 4.7 which is latest as of now.

Posts listing screen in admin displaying "Nothing Found" but counts are showing 3 posts and 3 published. In this scenario, I am able to create a new post but not able to see any post in listing.

For this I found a solution here : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44844/wordpress-iis7-sql-server-2008-not-showing-posts-displays-nothing-found

Above Solution is for old version of wordpress but I am able to apply it on current version.

Reason is breaking the query that returns the posts.

To fix this, Just go to "wp-includes/class-wp-query.php" line number: 2824 or search for below code :

```
$this->request = "SELECT $found_rows $distinct {$wpdb->posts}.ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} $join WHERE 1=1 $where $groupby $orderby $limits";
```

Replace it with:

```
$this->request = "SELECT $found_rows $distinct {$wpdb->posts}.ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} $join WHERE 1=1 $where $groupby $orderby";
```

I have just removed the $limit variable from the query which is responsible for the issue.

After Implementing this, my error have been fixed and posts are showing perfectly.

But this is a very bad practice to modify core files of wordpress. We should not modify the core files. I will not suggest anyone to proceed with this solution as it is not good way. If we update wordpress software in future, our modified file will automatically loose our fix.

So, I need help to make it happen without modifying the core wordpress files which is not a recommended way. If Anybody provide any other work around, please share.

Answer (score 0):

Now I have discovered a solution of above problem without modifying the core wordpress files. 
Actually the issue is due to the wp-db-abstraction plugin, so we need to modify that plugin files.

The problem is in translations.php file of plugin. Just go to the file and find the below mentioned code:

```
// Check for true offset
        if ( count($limit_matches) == 5 && $limit_matches[1] != '0' ) {
            $true_offset = true;
        } elseif ( count($limit_matches) == 5 && $limit_matches[1] == '0' ) {
            $limit_matches[1] = $limit_matches[4];
        }
```

Now replace it with:

```
// Check for true offset
        if ( count($limit_matches) == 5 && $limit_matches[1] != '0' ) {
            $true_offset = true;
        } elseif ( count($limit_matches) >= 5 && $limit_matches[1] == '0' ) {
            $limit_matches[1] = $limit_matches[4];
        }
```

After this just check the listing, it will work as per expectation. For more detail of the bug or to resolve more issues with IIS and SQL like pagination, just check here : http://www.wptricks24.com/post-listing-not-showing-wordpress-admin-iis-sql-server-database

This will definitely help someone.

Thanks